# Issue configuring Redmon port

Tags: redmon

I'm using Windows 10.  I have the redirected printer installed just fine.  But when I go to configure the port, after selecting my redirection program and putting in my arguments, when I click OK and error box pops up that says, "An error occurred during port configuration.  Incorrect function".

I've uninstalled and reinstalled Redmon.  I've deleted the ports and added new ones.  But still I keep getting this error.  I have admin control and all permissions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You might not have administrator permissions to configure the printer's port. What you can do is open the command prompt as an administrator and execute the following command:

```
rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /p /n "PRINTER"
```

Where PRINTER is any printer's name. That way you might be able to configure the port without the errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the port using the Print Management program, rather than the usual Printers & Scanners app, I'm not sure why though :)